# Mi favicon no funciona para dispositivos mobiles

Tags: wordpress, web

Hace poco empecé a desarrollar una website en wordpress, estoy usando el tema de OCEANWP la versión PRO sin embargo me he comunicado con ellos sin encontrar solución alguna.

He subido mi imagen (favicon) en el tamaño adecuado 512 x 512 en formato png, en la siguiente dirección Customize/site identity/site icon. Sin embargo este se muestra solamente en PC de escritorio pero no la versión móvil. He renombrando y vuelto ha subir el archivo, limpiado la caché y nada.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este plugin:
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/favicon-by-realfavicongenerator/

O bien introduciéndolo manualmente el siguiente código en el header.php:

```
<link rel=”icon” type=”image/x-icon” href=”http://www.yourwebsite.com/favicon.ico”>
```